# Swift Annotation Not Placed on MapView because viewForAnnotation not called

Tags: swift, annotations, mkmapview

I am working on an app that places a pin at the users current location as well as places pins based on input from the user for locations. The current location annotation is being placed fine, however when trying to place the user's input coordinates, the annotation is not placed.

I have added the annotation properly using `map.addAnnotation(annotation)` for which annotation.coordinate (for New York) is `CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.713054, longitude: -74.007227999999998)`.

I found that the `viewForAnnotation` method is not being called and I think this is the reason why the annotation is not being placed (printing the annotation results in nothing). I have a test app that requests input coordinates and it works in placing the annotation. Also in the test app, printing the annotation in viewForPrints out a value.

Below I have pasted some of the code I think is relevant to the issue. Please comment if you need more.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
class MapVC: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {



@IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    map.delegate = self
}
```

This function below takes the values from another class and converts the coordinates into CLLocationCoordinate2D type. As mentioned above, annotation.coordinate (for New York) yields `CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.713054, longitude: -74.007227999999998)`, so add works in saving the coordinates.

```
func add(newLocation location_one:[String:Any]) {
    let momentaryLat = (location_one["latitude"] as! NSString).doubleValue
    let momentaryLong = (location_one["longitude"] as! NSString).doubleValue
    
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.title = location_one["title"] as? String
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: momentaryLat as CLLocationDegrees, longitude: momentaryLong as CLLocationDegrees)
    


    map.addAnnotation(annotation) //not sure if this adds the annotation!

    self.map.centerCoordinate = annotation.coordinate
}

func mapView(_ map: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if (annotation is MKUserLocation) {
        return nil
    }
   
    let identifier = "pinAnnotation"
    var annotationView = map.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    
    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
    
    } else {
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    
    }
    map.showAnnotations(map.annotations, animated: true)
    return annotationView
}
```

Comment: "map.addAnnotation(annotation)" is this called in the main thread ?

Comment: Is the `add` method being called at all?

Comment: @MihaiFratu I used the add method for my code. It is in another viewController like such: map.add(newLocation:location_one). annotation.coordinate in my add method holds the appropriate coordinates. I believe the problem is that my viewForAnnotation is not being called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First,

`func mapView(_ map: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?`

This is a delegate method and is not used for setting the annotations,
It simply

> 1. Returns the view associated with the specified annotation object, i.e. The annotation view to display for the specified annotation or nil if you want to display a standard annotation view.`
> 2. If you do not implement this method, or if you return nil from your implementation for annotations other than the user location annotation, the map view uses a standard pin annotation view.`

Check it out here-

https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452045-mapview

The `addAnnotation()` method is enough for adding the default pin annotations. It may not be getting called because you may have called the

`func add(newLocation location_one:[String:Any])` from background queue, which calls `addAnnotatinon()` method inside.

If you are calling add method in some other controller that too on a background queue, may be some completion handlers, then you need to do it explicitly and call the add annotation method on the **main thread**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.map.addAnnotation(annotation) //Yes!! This method adds the annotations
}
```

For debugging purposes change your controller to this, even removing the delegates, then also you will get to see the annotations.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController:  UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
          annotation.title = "Test Location"
          annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.71304, longitude: -74.0072)
          self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
      }
}
```

So do ensure-

> 1. The addAnnotation method is called from the main thread
> 2. viewForAnnoation method - you use it to provide customisation to the default pin of the annotation.

Comment: Ah okay, I see so the problem lies in the fact that it isn't adding the annotation, and the viewFor has nothing to do with the issue. I am confused by what you mean by 'main thread' and what a 'background queue' is. Could you explain further?

Comment: I guess to clarify, I am passing information from another VC. In the mapView VC, the add method receives the information from a global array and attempts to place an annotation for each location.. Is there a way I can implement this into the viewDidLoad, because that seems to work perfectly fine.

Comment: @Kevin I was searching for some easier words to help you understand the concept of background queues, i will leave that for later. Now, is there any chance the array you are getting, *is from some web api?*

And you don't need to implement specifically in view did load, let you previous code be like that, just replace the addAnnotation with `DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.map.addAnnotation(annotation) 
}`

Comment: No I am not using any web api (JSON or XML). The array I am using is updated by the user from the other view controller. The user can input an address, and I have a reverse geocoder to turn the address into lat and long coordinates.

Comment: Can you add breakpoints to the `func add(newLocation location_one:[String:Any])`
 method of yours, and check if your **location_one** is not nil

Comment: It is not nil. When I inputted New York City into the other viewController, it passed it to the add method as ["latitude": "40.713054", "longitude": "-74.007228]. The passing of the location information works fine, but I believe the placing of the annotation is not working for some reason.

Comment: Could it be that when I try to typecast the information into the annotation like such: annotation.title = location_one["title"] as? String  ........                                            
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: momentaryLat as CLLocationDegrees, longitude: momentaryLong as CLLocationDegrees) is wrong?

Comment: That is not a problem, as long as you pass String or NSString from the other controller too, so your call from the other controller should be something like this - `self.add(newLocation: ["latitude":"40.713054", "longitude":"-74.007227999999998", "title":"New york"])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135460/discussion-between-saurabh-yadav-and-kevin).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need for using this `viewForAnnotation` function.Simply you can show annotation by giving coordinates for the annotation and put that into map by `map.addAnnotation(annotation)` function.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you not call `map.showAnnotations` in the `viewForAnnotation` method, because this is called everytime MapKit decides to draw annotation views -- so if there are multiple annotations available, the map will annoyingly relocate itself, which might result in an endless loop (not sure about the last, but I could think of circumstances when this might occur). You should only call `map.showAnnotations` upon user request (e.g. button press or other selection), to make the map center around those annotations.

Unfortunatly, your code works perfectly; hopefully you did not forget to call `add`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let loc = ["latitude": "40.713054", "longitude":"-74.00722", "title": "nyc"]
    add(newLocation: loc)
}
```

Here is the result:
[image]